# Bulk update cost on certain products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to bulk update the cost of certain items on my store. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561618/trying-to-locate-and-bulk-edit-woocommerce-prices-in-mysql) where a user says the following code can bulk update price:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta m 
    JOIN wp_posts p ON m.post_id=p.id 
    AND m.meta_key = '_price' 
    AND p.post_type = 'product'
SET m.meta_value = <price>
```

I'm gonna assume if I change *_price* to *_cost* it will work. Is that the correct term, or does anyone know how I can find it?

More importantly, am I able to target certain products by their categories or tags? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

There is **no term** like `_cost` in woocommerce.

There are ***3*** terms that **WooCommerce** use to store data in database:

1) `_regular_price` : As the name suggests, It is for the regular price of the product.

2) `_sale_price` : As the name suggests, It is for the **sale price** if the product is on sale and if product is not on sale then it will use `_regular_price`.

3) `_price` : Product is going to be sell based on `_price`. So suppose you have on product which is having `_regular_price` **22 $** and `_sale_price` **18 $** then product is going to sell at **18 $**. So basically you can say `_price` is decide by the `regular_price` and `_sale_price` both.

So there is not `_cost` term as per my knowledge and experience.

---

**Yes** you can target particular category but you need to dig in to database.

**First step** : Go to your database and find `wp_terms` table(`wp` is prefix and it might be different in your case).

**Step 2** : Find `term_id` of your category.

All the category assigned to the product in `wp_term_relationships`.

So you can write your query and put condition like `id(wp_post table) = object_id(wp_term_relationships table)`.

**NOTE:** Object ID and Post ID both are same in your database.