# How do I find the shipping class id in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Using [Hide shipping method for specific shipping classes in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718180/hide-shipping-method-for-specific-shipping-classes-in-woocommerce/47732732#47732732) answer code, I'm trying to hide shipping options based on shipping class.

Large items and small items have their own shipping class on our website and we only want to offer express shipping on small items.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE define your shipping class to find
    $class = 92;

    // HERE define the shipping method to hide
    $method_key_id = 'flat_rate:7';

    // Checking in cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // If we find the shipping class
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class ){
            unset($rates[$method_key_id]); // Remove the targeted method
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

I understand how to implement the code, however I don't know where to find the shipping class id, I can only find the slug and shipping class name

```
// HERE define your shipping class to find

$class = 92;
```

in the above example, where do I find the Id to replace the ***92***?

Thanks In advance.

Will

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make it work with shipping class **"Slugs"** you will use `WC_Product` `get_shipping_class()` method instead this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE define your shipping class SLUG
    $class_slug = 'large';

    // HERE define the shipping method to hide
    $method_key_id = 'flat_rate:7';

    // Checking in cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // If we find the shipping class
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() == $class_slug ){
            unset($rates[$method_key_id]); // Remove the targeted method
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)...

> Sometimes, you should may be need to refresh shipping methods going to shipping areas, then disable / save and re-enable / save your "flat rates" shipping methods.
>
> **To find the shipping methods IDs and the shipping classes IDs see below…**

---

**Finding the shipping class ID.**

1) In the database under `wp_terms` table:

Search for a term name or a term slug and you will get the term ID (the shipping class ID).

2) On Woocommerce shipping settings editing a "Flat rate", with your browser html inspector tool, inspect a shipping Class rate field like:

[image]

In the imput name attribute you have `woocommerce_flat_rate_class_cost_64`. So 64 is the ID for the shipping class.

---

**Get the shipping method rate ID:**

> To get the related **shipping methods rate IDs**, something like **`flat_rate:12`**, inspect with your browser code inspector each related radio button attribute **`name`** like:
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Need to make it method id an array

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // HERE define your shipping class SLUG
    $class_slug = 'pakketpost-klein';

    // HERE define the shipping method to hide
    $method_key_id = array('wbs:3e3ee71a_brievenbuspakje_klein', 'wbs:6a31d418_brievenbuspakje_middel', 'wbs:58d00327_brievenbuspakje_groot', 'pakketpost_groot', 'pakketpost_klein', 'standaard-verzending');


    // Checking in cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // If we find the shipping class
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class() == $class_slug ){
            unset($rates[$method_key_id]); // Remove the targeted method
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```